# Convert string containing date to Date

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

I'm having issues converting a string to date on swift, maybe it is something obvious but I don't get it.

I'm trying to convert **"Jan 18, 2022 04:39PM GMT"** this string into a Date. My code looks like this:

```
let str = "Jan 18, 2022 04:39PM GMT"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, YYYY hh:mma z"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)
print(date)
```

And console shows: **Optional(2021-12-19 16:39:00 +0000)**

Any idea what's wrong in this formatter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the Date being shown as an Optional, your format string appears to be wrong. "YYYY" should be "yyyy", so the whole line that assigns the formatter should be:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy hh:mma z"
```

That change yields the output

"Optional(2022-01-18 16:39:00 +0000)"

In addition, you should really force the calendar to Gregorian or iso8601, and set its locale to `"en_US_POSIX`:

An improved version of the date formatter could would look like this:

(from Leo's edit.)

```
let str = "Jan 18, 2022 04:39PM GMT"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = .init(identifier: .iso8601)
dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy hh:mma z"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str) {
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(dateString == str)  // true
}
```

Comment: This will only solve the capital Y issue. But OP code will have many issues. If the user device calendar is set to Buddhist calendar the year will be offset more than 500 years.

Comment: Fair point. It should really be reworked to force a Gregorian calendar. I just addressed the reason for the unexpected output the OP was asking about.

Comment: Yes and there is many other issues if OP wants to create a string from date using that formatter

Comment: Feel free to write a more complete answer that addresses those other issues.

Comment: I can't answer date related posts anymore. It will never end. So many posts about dates I thing it doesnt help when people search SO. It ends up being a one to one and that's not the goal of this forum.

Comment: You need to set the timezone when going the other way. Btw you forgot the calendar as well.

Comment: @LeoDabus Doesn't the `iso8601DateFormatter` force an iso8601 calendar? I always assumed it does.

Comment: You are not using `ISO8601DateFormatter`. I don't think you can use `ISO8601DateFormatter` for this date format. I would need to check its options

Comment: You're right on both counts. That'll teach me to edit answers while on a conference call...

Answer (score 0):

The code written for converting date is correct, also converted date is correct. But final result is optional so you are getting date like Optional(2021-12-19 16:39:00 +0000).
Also the date formatter is wrong.
So please unwrap the date to get actual date without optional.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy hh:mma z"
guard let convertedDate = date else {
return
}
print(convertedDate)
```

Comment: The date returned "2021-12-19" does not match the input date. ("Jan 18, 2022") The OPs format string was wrong. (See my answer)

Comment: yeah , I missed that issue.Looks like date formatter is causing that issue. Thanks @DuncanC